# running an algorithm over multiple files using multiple input files in linux

Tags: r, arrays, bash, shell, bioinformatics

I am running this code (from https://github.com/weizhouUMICH/SAIGE/wiki/Genetic-association-tests-using-SAIGE#flowchart):

```
Rscript step2_SPAtests.R \
        --vcfFile=./input/genotype_10markers.vcf.gz \
        --vcfFileIndex=./input/genotype_10markers.vcf.gz.tbi \
        --vcfField=GT \
        --chrom=1 \
    --minMAF=0 \
        --minMAC=0.5 \
        --maxMAFforGroupTest=0.01       \
        --sampleFile=./input/samplelist.txt \
        --GMMATmodelFile=./output/example_quantitative.rda \
        --varianceRatioFile=./output/example_quantitative_cate.varianceRatio.txt \
        --SAIGEOutputFile=./output/example_quantitative.SAIGE.gene.txt \
        --numLinesOutput=1 \
        --groupFile=./input/groupFile_geneBasedtest_simulation.txt    \
        --sparseSigmaFile=./output/example_quantitative_cate.varianceRatio.txt_relatednessCutoff_0.125.sparseSigma.mtx       \
        --IsSingleVarinGroupTest=TRUE
```

I want to run it over 22 chromosome files so the vcfFile, vcfFileindex, chrom, SAIGEOUtputFile and groupFile inputs will be different e.g.
`chromosome1.vcf.gz/chromosome1.vcf.gz.tbi/chrom=1/chromsome1_output.txt/chromosome1_groupfile.txt`
will be the first input and `chromosome22.vcf.gz/chromosome22.vcf.gz.tbi/chrom=22/chromsome22_output.txt/chromosome22_groupfile.txt` will be the last input

These are huge files and will take a long time to run so I don't really want to get it wrong too many time before. If I provide a list of files as the inputs and desired outputs (SAIGEoutput) in chromosome numerical order will the algorithm run it that way i.e. will each input move through 1..22 synced up?

```
#all files are in a chromosome order from 001 to 022    
vcfFiles = $(<vcflist.txt)
vcFileIndex = $(<vcfindex.txt)
chrom=${1..22}
SAIGEoutputFile=$(<outputlist.txt)
Groupfile=$(<groupfile_list.txt)

Rscript step2_SPAtests.R \
            --vcfFile=${vcfFiles} \
            --vcfFileIndex=${vcFileIndex}\
            --vcfField=GT \
            --chrom=${chrom} \
        --minMAF=0 \
            --minMAC=0.5 \
            --maxMAFforGroupTest=0.01       \
            --sampleFile=./input/samplelist.txt \
            --GMMATmodelFile=./output/example_quantitative.rda \
            --varianceRatioFile=./output/example_quantitative_cate.varianceRatio.txt \
            --SAIGEOutputFile=${SAIGEoutputFile} \
            --numLinesOutput=1 \
            --groupFile=${Groupfile}    \
            --sparseSigmaFile=./output/example_quantitative_cate.varianceRatio.txt_relatednessCutoff_0.125.sparseSigma.mtx       \
            --IsSingleVarinGroupTest=TRUE
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a loop for this. Take a look at this:

```
for i in {1..22}; {
    echo $i
}
```

The output will be:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
```

Same can be done with your command:

```
for i in {1..22}; {
    Rscript step2_SPAtests.R \
    --vcfFile=chromosome$i.vcf.gz \
    --vcfFileIndex=chromosome$i.vcf.gz.tbi \
    --vcfField=GT \
    --chrom=$i \
    --minMAF=0 \
    --minMAC=0.5 \
    --maxMAFforGroupTest=0.01       \
    --sampleFile=./input/samplelist.txt \
    --GMMATmodelFile=./output/example_quantitative.rda \
    --varianceRatioFile=./output/example_quantitative_cate.varianceRatio.txt \
    --SAIGEOutputFile=chromsome${i}_output.txt \
    --numLinesOutput=1 \
    --groupFile=chromosome${i}_groupfile.tx    \
    --sparseSigmaFile=./output/example_quantitative_cate.varianceRatio.txt_relatednessCutoff_0.125.sparseSigma.mtx       \
    --IsSingleVarinGroupTest=TRUE
}
```

Notice that somewhere `$i` is enclosed in `{}` that is because `$i_` - valid variable name but our var is `$i`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer Ivan! Worked well. Will read up on loops! The next question might be on how to run this as an array on a HPC...

Comment: @tacrolimus glad to help. Te simplest variant to bust this is add `&` at the end of your script like this `...upTest=TRUE &` it'l run all 22 instances at once in background.

Comment: Yes, otherwise whole loop will be running on background and start instances one by one.